# PDF reader for Linux which supports one click dictionary lookups

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-viewer, dictionary

Is there a PDF reader for Linux which supports the following:

If you click on a word, it opens a dictionary like [ding](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ding) or even better [linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com/) and translates the word from a predefined source language into a predefined target language.

Currently I mark the word, copy it to the clipboard open the dictionary and then look it up. I am looking for a way to make this process faster and more comfortable.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I included a link to the man page. See also: https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~fri/ding/

Comment: Thank you!  I hope someone can answer you question for you.